# Java technologies learning path

Tags: java

I need to learn fairly quickly the following Java related technologies:

- XML(JAXP, JAXB)
- Web Services (JAX-WS, JAX-RPC)
- Web (Servlet, JSP, JSF)
- JDBC, JPA, Hibernate, Spring Framework including Spring AOP

What is the best order for learning?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722121/what-should-i-learn-first-spring-or-hibernate

Comment: What will you do after lunch, then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a pretty tall order.

I'd recommend starting small with a personal project.  Start on something that you feel passionate about and feel like you could stick with for a while.  Note, that this could **actually be the hardest part**.

You're probably better of making a simple web app and growing it into something that offers services etc...

Without context and practice, I don't think just learning X, Y, then Z in any particular order will do you any good.

Answer (score 2):

Start with servets, JSPs using JSTL, and JDBC.  You can go a long way just with those, and they're the basis for all the others.

Answer (score 1):

Start with Spring. Work through Spring in Action, Third Edition by Craig Walls. It gives you a good intro to Spring and touches all the other technologies you mentioned, although more about how to integrate them with Spring. But you get the ideas. Then dive into the specific topics as needed, ideally by working on a project. And expect it to take some time. Worked for me.